# Memory leaks when using a singleton

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have a class in which I implement the singelton design pattern.
I know some people don't think its a good idea, but it helps a lot,

Anyway - I have a memory leak and vlagrind points me to these lines:

```
_singleton = new Manager(); //Manager::instance() (Manager.cpp:18)
```

And

```
Manager::Manager() : _file(new ofstream), _tasks(new map<int, Task *>()),
        _idState(new map<int, int>()), _closing(false), _pending(false),
        _lock(new pthread_mutex_t), _endLock(new pthread_mutex_t),  _cond(new pthread_cond_t),
        _flushCond(new map<int, pthread_cond_t *>()), _attr(new pthread_attr_t) {
//The last line is line 25 in Manager::Manager
```

Now in Manager's destructor I can't explicitly delete it, because it creates a silly loop (as destructor will be called when deleting _singleton resulting in an infinite loop). How do I get rid of this leak? Thanks!

P.s. here is Valgrind's output:

```
==17823== 512 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==17823==    at 0x4C27297: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17823==    by 0x40151E: Manager::Manager() (Manager.cpp:25)
==17823==    by 0x4014DB: Manager::instance() (Manager.cpp:18)
==17823==    by 0x406475: initdevice(char*) (outputdevice.cpp:66)
==17823==    by 0x4061D5: main (driver.cpp:21)
==17823== 
==17823== LEAK SUMMARY:
==17823==    definitely lost: 512 bytes in 1 blocks
=    =17823==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17823==      possibly lost: 288 bytes in 1 blocks
==17823==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17823==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Addition: here's the code where I create Manager:

```
Manager.h:
class Manager {
public:
    ~Manager();
    static Manager * instance();
private:
    Manager();
    static Manager * _singleton;
};
```

And the implementation:

```
Manager.cpp:
Manager * Manager::_singleton = 0;

Manager * Manager::instance() {
    if (!_singleton)
        _singleton = new Manager();
    return _singleton;
}
```

Comment: "Now in Manager's destructor I can't explicitly delete it, because it creates a silly loop." - what does that mean?

Comment: show us how you create and destroy instance of Manager.

Comment: Don't do it with pointers and it works much better. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/14065 It even becomes thread safe on gcc (see notes in linked question). Even if you use pointers you should never return a pointer you should return a reference from `instance()` otherwise the caller is unsure if they should delete the object and they never should.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Singleton design pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern)

Comment: I usually use deleaker for similar cases (Windows only).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One common way of implementing singleton in C++ is making the instance a function-static `std::unique_ptr<T>` inside the instance getter, rather than a class-static variable. This ensures a call of destructor upon program's completion, and lets you create an instance that gets accessed polymorphically e.g. through a pointer to an abstract base class.

Scott Meyers provided a good discussion of this topic in [his "More Effective C++" book](http://www.aristeia.com/books.html).

Comment: I don't think that this is the problem as I call the destructor explicitly

Comment: @yotamoo You aren't using it in multithreaded environment, are you? Because if two threads try getting the instance concurrently, one of them will leak the `Manager`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight While it is a correct concern, it would be very weird if he saw this reproduced consistently.

Comment: 1. If it's in a unique_ptr it doesn't matter what scope it's in.  It can be global and it will still release as the program terminates.  2. The Meyers singleton doesn't use a pointer, it uses a static variable and returns its address.

Answer (score 2):

Make `Manager` a static object, and it's constructor and destructor will automatically be called.  Or if you must allocate it with operator new, put it in a smart pointer (unique_ptr if you can, otherwise auto_ptr) such that it will be destroyed when the pointer is.

Comment: Good answer except that when you make the variable static then you may need to worry about global creation order if your singleton is used in the initialization of any globals.  Thus a good place for it is probably in the "instance()" function as the Meyers singleton does.  This guarantees order because the first function use forces initialization.

Comment: Thus the "if you must allocate it with operator new" bit -- dependencies in creation order are isomorphic to constructor arguments.